# Add scroll to an image when its near its top/bottom edge, simple and clear JS solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a "simple and clear" solution to work in this case:

On mobile

User is scrolling trough an image (which is 100vw, or full screen) and stops near the top/bottom of that image (lets say 100px), in this case I want to that image auto scroll to its up/down edge.

I have an example to illustrate my point:

[JSFiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/gfpyd2j0/)

```js
var timeout = 600;
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".section").each(function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var offset = $(this).offset().top;
      if (offset - scrollTop < 200 && offset - scrollTop > -200) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, '600');
        return;
      }
    });
  }, timeout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="section-1">
  Section 1
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-2">
  Section 2
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

In the example the solution suffers from screen stroking/flickering and other horrible)) stuff.

Ideally I want something like CSS Scroll Snap behavior, but I can't apply it in this case.

Is it possible to use simple things (like jQuery `.scrollTo` `.animate`, etc.) and don't mess with the rest of a page?

Comment: I'm not sure about the *«stroking/flickering and other horrible stuff»* you talk about.... I don't see anything like. Your code works fine.

Comment: This is not my code, just an example and it is working fine, but the point is - this is awful user experience on every browser, especially on mobile @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfectly even like that but I guess in other computers it might differ.
Maybe try a different approach and debounce so you won't add a timer and remove it so many times.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};


var timeout = 600;
var timer;
$(window).scroll(debounce(250, function(event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".section").each(function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var offset = $(this).offset().top;
      if (offset - scrollTop < 200 && offset - scrollTop > -200) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, '600');
        return;
      }
    });
  }, timeout);
})function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
var timeout;
return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
};
```

};);

Comment: Trying to figure it out your code by adding it to JSFiddel, it seems it has an mistyping or errors, can you please recheck it? @Haim Houri